# IBM Ration DOORS - DXL script

Tags: ibm-doors

I want to move the Heading Text to Object Text, particularly in all Heading4 objects but Heading numbers should be retained. 
Is there any in built functions present for this operations or do we need to write a DXL script for this.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning Heading Numbers:
The mechanism is always that if Object Heading is filled, then the heading number is shown, if it is not filled, then the number is not shown. So you cannot empty the heading if you want a number.

Perhaps an alternative would be to set the object text to original object heading and to set the object heading to a single dot “.”. Not nice but might work.

Well, you could export Object Identifier, Object Number, Heading and Text to a csv file, modify it in Excel (use a filter to only show objects of level 4, swap headline from Object Heading to Object Text, enter the dot for new Object Heading) and reimport the file in update mode.

But I think you are better off using a DXL script, it's usually faster and easier to handle.

The dxl command to copy the attribute is simply

```
set(oCurrent."Object Text", oCurrent."Object Heading")" 
oCurrent."Object Heading" = "."
```

You can detect in which level you are by using the `level` function, like

```
if (4 == level (oCurrent) && some_additional_conditions?) ...
```